# Frank Wolfe algorithms for non-convex optimization

Tags: vector-analysis, non-convex-optimization

I have a non-convex function as follow

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG7Rv.jpg)

where: $\alpha < 1$ and $\theta \in \bigtriangleup_{K}$ means:

$\theta_1 + \theta_2 + ... + \theta_K = 1$  and  $\theta_i \ge \epsilon > 0, \quad i=1,...,K$ ($\epsilon$ is a small constant)

I design a FW algorithm as follows:

[click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leXkr.jpg)

How can I evaluate the convergence rate of the algorithm above? Can I change step size to achieve the convergence rate is O(1/t)? (t is number of iterations)

Comment: It'd be better to write the optimization problem in the body of the question.

Comment: I've just edited the problem. It's very nice if you review